# Finding a stationary point of a equation of nth dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, quadratic-forms

I am given the following question:

[image]

It asks for the values of $a$ for which it is stationary.  Hence, I'm expecting that the question are asking the value of $a$ when it is a stationary point.  However, after the following calculation:

[image]

I came to a conclusion that $a=0$.  However, the question mentions "valueS" which implies that there are more than one.  What went wrong with my process?

(Also, since the question also asks for the values of "v" which gives this stationary point, then doesn't the stationary point exist for all values of v?)

Comment: The 4th line should be $(A-\alpha I)\vec{v}=0$. So $\alpha$ should be the eigenvalue(s) of $A$, and $\vec{v}$ should be the corresponding eigenvector(s).

Comment: @KittyL ahh oops, careless mistake from me crossing out v. Problem solved. Thanks!